# Get list of all notebooks in my databricks workspace

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, databricks, azure-databricks

How do I get a list of all notebooks in my workspace & store their names along with full path in csv file, I have tried using Databricks CLI option but that doesn't seem to have recursive operation.

[databricks workspace list](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see in code there is no recursive option:
https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/blob/master/databricks_cli/workspace/cli.py (def ls_cli)

Example solution is to import cli in python and extend it:

```
from databricks_cli.sdk import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.sdk import service


host = "your_host"
token = "your_token"

client = ApiClient(host=host, token=token)
objects = []
workspace = service.WorkspaceService(client)

def list_workspace_objects(path):
    elements = workspace.list(path).get('objects')
    if elements is not None:
        for object in elements:
            objects.append(object)
            if(object['object_type'] == 'DIRECTORY'):
                list_workspace_objects(object['path'])


list_workspace_objects("/")

print(objects)
```

Comment: Thanks you, that's exactly what needed !

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code directly . Note : Tested Code

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    import base64
    import requests
    import json
    
    databricks_instance ="databricks Instance"
    
    url_list = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.0/workspace/list"
    url_export = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.0/workspace/export"
    
    
    payload = json.dumps({
      "path": "/"
    })
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    notebooks = []
    
    # Getting the all notebooks list for given notebooks.
    
    def list_notebooks(mylist):
      for element in mylist['objects']:
        if element['object_type'] == 'NOTEBOOK':
          notebooks.append(element)
        if element['object_type'] == 'DIRECTORY':
          payload_inner = json.dumps({
            "path": element['path']
          })
          response_inner = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers, data=payload_inner).json()
          if len(response_inner) != 0:
            list_notebooks(response_inner)
      return notebooks
    
    result = list_notebooks(response)
    print(result[0])
```